# What's the meaning (and method to provide) the -d and -u arguments?

Tags: json, scala, rest, paypal, playframework

I'm trying to make a WS GET call using the Playframework in Scala to invoke the Paypal REST JSON API. I'm more specifically trying to [get the initial Paypal access token](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/):

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I build this in Scala by doing:

```
@Inject(ws: WSClient)

val url = config.get[String]("paypal.url.token") // https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
val httpHeaders = Array(
    "Accept" -> "application/json",
    "Accept-Language" -> "en_US"
)
val username = config.get[String]("paypal.client_id")
val password = config.get[String]("paypal.secret")
val request: WSRequest = ws.url(url).withHttpHeaders(httpHeaders: _*).
    withRequestTimeout(timeout).
    withAuth(username, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
val futureResponse = request.get()
futureResponse.map { response =>
    println(response.json)
}
```

I here assumed that `-u` in the original `curl` sample meant and corresponded to `withAuth` but I don't know what the `-d` for `grant_type=client_credentials` corresponds to?

When I run it like it is now I get the following error:
`{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Authorization header does not have valid access token"}`

and some when before the log:
`[info] p.s.a.o.a.n.h.i.Unauthorized401Interceptor - Can't handle 401 as auth was already performed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read `curl` manual with `man curl`.

So, 
1) `-u` represents `--user <username:passsword>`

> ```
>    -u, --user <user:password>
>           Specify the user name and password to use for server authentication. Overrides -n, --netrc and --netrc-optional.
>
>           If you simply specify the user name, curl will prompt for a password.
> ```

This also translates to `-H "Authorization: <Basic|Bearer> base64_for_username:password"`

2) `-d` represents the `--data` or payload on POST request.

> ```
>    -d, --data <data>
>           (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
>           filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the  con-
>           tent-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F, --form.
> ```

- Verify `withAuth(username, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)` is taking right username, password
- and also set the post body in scala which is missing in your code. I don't know much playframework but this could be right way - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.3/api/java/play/libs/ws/WSRequest.html#post-java.lang.String-

Comment: Following your answer and switching to post solves the OP. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `post` instead of a `get` like so

```
ws
  .url(url)
  .withAuth(username, password, WSAuthScheme.BASIC)
  .post(Map("grant_type" -> Seq("client_credentials")))
  .map(println)
```

Comment: very cool the `.map(println)` bit for debugging purposes :) as post data I used simply a String `val body = "grant_type=client_credentials"` and it worked.